# jfreechart export SVG size issue

Tags: java, jfreechart

I am using `JFreeChart`, and I want to export my Chart to SVG. I refer this [code](http://dolf.trieschnigg.nl/jfreechart/).

If I send `Rectangle bounds` parameter like

new Rectangle(100,100);

then I get the complete image(Chart). But for another dimension, I get cropped image(Chart).

What I miss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fond solution.

we need to give input in the Same ratio as image have.